# Web wallet for Monero where I can use view-only wallet and generate offline transactions

Tags: mymonero

Can anyone recommend a Web wallet for Monero where I can type in only my public view key and XMR address and then generate an offline transaction that I can export into the Monero GUI to 'accept' or validate? I went to wallet.mymonero.com but the 'Next' key is not enabled when I enter just those two pieces of data and keeping the 'Spend key' field empty. Perhaps Guarda?

Comment: As far as I know, currently no web wallets support this functionality.

Comment: So to be clear, wallets created with Monero GUI/Monero app - which are cold wallets created on hardware devices - cannot be restored & used on web wallets and can only be restored on other hardware devices? What about wallets created by offline wallet generators like https://moneroaddress.org - can they be restored on both hardware devices and web wallets? What about the XMR address that is shown in the Monero app on the device? On my Nano S, the Monero app keeps showing the same XMR address even if I create a new wallet that has a different XMR address - what's going on with this? Regards

Comment: That's inaccurate. To reiterate, you cannot use webwallets to create some kind of view wallet. However, you can still restore from the 25 word mnemonic seed. You have also have to differentiate between 'normal' XMR wallets (which generate 25 word mnemonic seeds) and Ledger Monero wallets (where the 24 word Ledger mnemonic seed is your Monero seed). The Ledger mnemonic seed first has to be converted to a standard Monero seed in order to use it in a different wallet. As I said before, a given 24 word Ledger mnemonic seed always corresponds to a certain XMR public address. 1/

Comment: You can create numerous wallet files, but they will all match. If you, however, create a non Ledger Monero wallet, it will have a different public address. 2/

Comment: 'You can create numerous wallet files, but they will all match.' I don't understand - can you clarify? Also, what about wallets created by offline wallet generators like moneroaddress.org - can I restore/use them in the Monero GUI with the Nano? If not, what 'cold wallet' and 'hot wallet' apps do I use them in?

Comment: As long as the 24 word mnemonic seed of the Ledger device stays the same, the GUI will always generate the same Ledger Monero wallet (with the same public address). 1/

Comment: You can import / restore those in the GUI, yes. However, you cannot import them in your Ledger device. The definition of hot and cold wallets is kind of tricky. Perhaps this warrants a separate question? 2/